# Condition on an expression to have an integer solution

Tags: number-theory

I have an expression $$f=\frac{\sqrt{884m-1}-\sqrt{4m-1}}{2}$$ What is the condition on $m$ for which $f$ is an integer. Also is it possible to prove $f/110$ can never be an integer? 
P.S: $m$ need not be an integer. From what I can see $m$ should be of the form $k+0.5$ for some $k$. I was wondering if a tighter condition on $m$ be derived.
The solutions I found by assuming that odd squares are of the form $8r+1$ for some $r$ are:
$$m=0.5,2.5,18090.5,117992.5,4034072.5,...$$ Can a pattern be derived for this?
More generally, what is the condition for an integral solution of$$f=\frac{\sqrt{4gm-1}-\sqrt{4m-1}}{g-1}$$ for some integer $g$?

Comment: The second radical can never be an integer (since no integer has a square of the form $4m-1$); so you would need neither of the radicals to be integers and for them to cancel out...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin
Thanks Arturo, but I never mentioned $m$ should be an integer. In fact $m$ has to be of the form $k+0.5$ for some $k$ for it to work. I wish to know if a tighter condition can be derived?

Comment: Well, then you should say so in the body of the question. The use of $m$ (as opposed to $x$ or some other variable) suggests integers (or even positive integers). Put **all** conditions you are considering in the body of the question, don’t wait until someone makes a mistaken assumption, and then bury the information in comments.

Comment: True.. Did so, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For $\sqrt{4m-1}$ to be an integer, $m=\frac{n^2+1}{4}$

If so, then $884m-1=221n^2+220$, and this must be a square, call it $r^2$

We get $221n^2+220-r^2=0$, which by quadratic formula (after a little manipulation) requires $n=\frac{\sqrt{221(r^2-220)}}{221}$.

The easiest solution to this (I haven't looked to see if it is the only one) is seen to be $r^2-220=221$, making $r=21$ and $n=1$

This in turn gives $m=0.5$, which plugged into the original equation yields $f=10$.

Comment: I followed something similar and found a set of solutions. I will update the original question. Still I cannot prove that $f$ is never divisible by 110.

Answer (score 1):

1)

Let $a^2=884m-1$ and $b^2=4m-1$.

Find polynomial $P(f,m)$, where $f \in \Bbb Z$ and $m \in \Bbb Q$:

```
? polresultant(2*f - a + b, 884*m - 1 - a^2, a)
%9 = -4*f^2 - 4*b*f + (884*m + (-b^2 - 1))
? polresultant(%, 4*m - 1 - b^2, b)
%10 = 16*f^4 + (-7104*m + 16)*f^2 + 774400*m^2
? %/16
%11 = f^4 + (-444*m + 1)*f^2 + 48400*m^2
```

$P(f,m)=f^4 + f^2 - 444f^2m  + 48400m^2=0$

Some numerically solutions [in Wolfram](http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/11.1559449784.png).

2)

Let $f=110h$, then $h^2 + 12100 h^4 - 444 h^2 m + 4 m^2=0$ and numerically this equation have not solutions for $0<h<10^6$.

$2 \mid h$. Let $h=2t$, then $m^2 - 444 m t^2 + t^2 + 48400 t^4=t^2 - 884 t^4 + (222 t^2 - m)^2=0$.

If exist $\sqrt{884 t^4 - t^2} \in \Bbb Z$, then $m=\sqrt{884 t^4 - t^2} - 222 t^2 \in \Bbb Z$. But $m \notin \Bbb Z$. This contradiction, i.e. $110 \nmid f$.

3)

$$f=\frac{\sqrt{4gm-1}-\sqrt{4m-1}}{g-1}$$

$f,g \in \Bbb Z$ and $m \in \Bbb Q$

$P(f,g,m)=4 f^2 + f^4 - 2 f^4 g + f^4 g^2 - 8 f^2 m - 8 f^2 g m + 16 m^2=0$.

This equation [have many solutions](http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/11.1559454193.png).

After simplify $4 f^2 - 4 f^4 g + (f^2 (g + 1) - 4 m)^2=0$.

Then condition on $m$ for $f$ and $g$ is $s=\sqrt{4 f^4 g-4 f^2}-f^2 (g + 1) \in \Bbb Z$ and $4 \nmid s$. $f$ is depends on $g$ from Pell equation $gf^2-1=y^2$. If for given $g$ exist solution $(f,y)$ this Pell equation, then $s=2fy-f^2(g+1)$.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. My question for the last part is what is the condition on $m$ for $f$ to have an integral solution? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Could you please inform why did you assume $2|h$?

Comment: I tried $g=61$, but I get to the same condition. In this case how will you prove $30\not| f$?

Comment: If $g=61$, then $f^2(1-61f^2)+(31f^2-2m)^2=0$. Let $f=30h$, then $900 h^2 (1 - 54900 h^2) + (27900 h^2 - 2 m)^2=0$. Equation $1 - 54900 h^2=y^2$ has solution only for $h=0$, then $30 \nmid f$.

Comment: @dmitry-ezhov I think there is a small error in your expression. After simplification, I get $(f^2-m(g+1))^2-4m^2g+f^2=0$, not the expression you gave. So maybe can you correct it? Also, I found by running a brute force program that if $g=61$, then $30|f$ for $m=280947882.5$. So, how can that be proved by your procedure?

Comment: @RTn I do not see my error: [link](http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/11.1559665262.png). How did you get $(f^2-m(g+1))^2-4m^2g+f^2$?

Comment: @DmitryEzhov You are right. I am mistaken and I apologize. I confused between the numerical example and the general case given by the OP. In one case the denominator is $2$ and other case it is $g-1$. In any case, can your expression prove that  $f=\frac{\sqrt{4gm-1}-\sqrt{4m-1}}{2}$ is divisible or not by $(g-1)/2$ (extending the logic of the numerical example of the OP)? I tried by extending your idea that $m\notin \mathbb{Z}$, but unless I use a computer  (and prove or disprove that the Pell equation has no solution), I am unable to prove so.

Comment: OP equation is fine. Other similar equation $f=\frac{\sqrt{gm-1}\pm\sqrt{m-1}}{g+1}$:  [link](https://dxdy.ru/topic135024.html), where also $f$ and $m$ is dependent from $g$ by Pell equation.

Answer (score 0):

►Answering to the O.P's question about $\dfrac {f}{110}$.

We know $m$ can not be integer. We go to integers putting $m$ rational as $m=\dfrac{p^2+q^2}{4q^2}$ where $p$ and $q$ are coprime integers. Then we have $\sqrt{4m-1}=\dfrac pq$ and $\sqrt{884m-1}=\dfrac{\sqrt{221p^2+220q^2}}{q}$

Then 
$$f=\frac{\sqrt{221p^2+220q^2}-p}{2q}$$ If $f$ is an integer we have one equation in three integer unknowns $p,q,n$:
$$221p^2+220q^2=(2qn+p)^2$$ simplifying, $$55(p^2+q^2)=qn(qn+p)$$ Because of $\dfrac pq$ is irreducible we can reduce to two integers because dividing by $q$ we see that $q|55$ then $q\in\{1,5.11,55\}$. It follows **all possible values of the integer $n$** are implicit in the following  four quadratic equations (without $q$):
$$\begin{cases}55p^2-np+55-n^2=0\\55p^2-5np+25\cdot55-(5n)^2=0\\55p^2-11pn+121\cdot55-(11n)^2=0\\55p^2-55np+55^3-(55n)^2=0\end{cases}$$ Solving in $p$ and $n$ each of these quadratics, one has discriminants  which should be all squares. To avoid bad writing in English, we explicit the corresponding formulas:
$$\begin{cases}110p=n\pm\sqrt{221n^2-12100}\\2n=-p\pm\sqrt{221p^2+220}\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}22p=n\pm\sqrt{221n^2-12100}\\10n=-p\pm\sqrt{221p^2+5500}\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}10p=n\pm\sqrt{221n^2-12100}\\22n=-p\pm\sqrt{221p^2+26620}\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}2p=n\pm\sqrt{221n^2-12100}\\110n=-p\pm\sqrt{221p^2+665500}\end{cases}$$

**Is $\dfrac {f}{110}$ never an integer?**

To study this we put $110n$ instead of $n$ in any of the above equations in two integer unknowns. Note that all the four discriminants in $n$ are equal. One has the four cases
$$\begin{cases}p=n\pm\sqrt{221n^2-1}\\p=5n\pm5\sqrt{221n^2-1}\\p=11n\pm11\sqrt{221n^2-1}\\p=55n\pm55\sqrt{221n^2-1}\end{cases}$$ Since $\dfrac pq$ is irreducible we have to keep just the first equation $$p=n\pm\sqrt{221n^2-1}$$ We look at the equation $$x^2-221y^2=-1$$

According to the oeis given by the OP himself in a comment below, this equation has no solution.

Thus $\dfrac{f}{110}$ is never integer.

Comment: @Piquito Thanks for the solution, but can you edit it for $f/110$ please? That way, the answer will be correct.

Comment: No, $X^2-221Y^2=-1$ does not have any integer solution. So please correct your answer. Thanks.

Comment: In this case your assertion about $\dfrac{f}{110}$ is proved. If you are right then I have had a confusion with $\pm1$ in the field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{221})$. Anyway, I just wanted to satisfy your question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.. Can you please also correct your answer to reflect that?

Comment: For the moment I am not convinced that the Pell-Fermat equation has not solution with $-1$ (with $1$ has an infinity). Are you sure?. Write yourself or anybody else the given proof. Greetings.

Comment: Here you go 
https://oeis.org/A031396

Convinced?

Comment: Well, that list being "exhaustive", we can conclude that the integers omitted are not "solubles". Well, dear friend, I correct, happily, of course.